# Как воспроизвести аудиопоток методами pyglet на python без сохранения в файл?

Tags: python, аудио

На руках **python3.5** , **pyglet** с **avbin**-ом и библиотека **requests**

Каким образом возможно воспроизведение аудиопотока с сайта(например, с 
[ic7.101.ru:8000/c15_3](http://ic7.101.ru:8000/c15_3)
 ) без сохранения его в файл(с помощью буфферизации) средставми python3 совместно с pyglet?
Повторюсь, запись в файл не нужна, следовательно функция pyglet.media.load отпадает

B доках непонятно описывается класс StreamingSource

Когда кидаю в плеер (pyglet.media.Player()) после того, как вызывал метод get_audio_source(<данные>) кучу раз, выбрасывает ошибку о том, что в данном объекте source атрибут duration равен None

Код:

```
import pyglet, requests

req = requests.get('http://ic7.101.ru:8000/c15_3', stream=True)

player = pyglet.media.Player()

source = pyglet.media.StreamingSource()

CHUNK = 1024

for num, chunk in enumerate(req.iter_content(CHUNK)):
    if num == 1000:
        break
    source.get_audio_data(chunk)
    if num == 100:
        player.queue(source)
        player.play()
        pyglet.app.run()
pyglet.clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: pyglet.app.exit(), source.duration)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.PyCharmCE2017.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 16, in <module>
    player.queue(source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyglet/media/__init__.py", line 978, in queue
    group.queue(source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyglet/media/__init__.py", line 698, in queue
    self.duration += source.duration
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Также возможно использование mp3player или pyaudio

*Gstreamer не предлагать, т.к. не ставится*

Comment: Ссылку на доки не присылать.
Понял бы там что-нибудь, сюда бы не писал

Comment: a на что ж вам тогда ссылку присылать?

Comment: Так вы укажите эту проблему в вопросе.